# Filtering Get-WmiObject by date on Windows Server 2003 with Where-Object

Tags: powershell, datetime, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2003

Im trying to filter this query by date (get values after $time). I am not doing this at -filter parameter cause i am getting error on a Windows Server 2003 SP2.

```
$colLogFiles = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NTLogEvent -ComputerName "localhost" | Where-Object {($_.EventType -eq "1") -or (($_.EventType -eq "2") -and ($_.TimeGenerated -gt $time))}
```

But that last condition it is not doing anything and i think it is because datetime format its not being recognized. An example of $_.TimeGenerated is 20181213144843.186997-000

Exists any way to do this or change that datetime format?

Comment: Try replacing `$_.TimeGenerated` with `$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated)`

Comment: Use `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NTLogEvent -ComputerName "localhost" | Select-Object -Property timegenerated | gm` to find that the TimeGenerated property is a `String` type.

Comment: @boxdog I got an exception when calling "ParseExact":  "Unable to recognize the string as a valid DateTime value."

Comment: @lit it is: `timegenerated NoteProperty string timegenerated=20190114135011.640597-000`

Comment: The suggestion wasn't to call `ParseExact`. Use the special `ConvertToDateTime` method that's present on the object itself. (And ensure `$time` is a valid `DateTime`, or convertible to it.) Note that, because the strings are of the form `YYYYMMDD`, they *do* order lexicographically: `-gt '20190114'`, for example, will work, even though the comparison isn't done as a date/time value.

Comment: Although `($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated))` as @boxdog comments works, the `ConvertToDate` method converts the UTC string returned by WMI to a localized DateTime object but with a glitch.. The `.Kind` property of the returned date is set to `Unspecified` and actually should be set to `Local`. To do this, you need something like `[DateTime]::new(($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.TimeGenerated)).Ticks, 'Local')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making it in Python with the library win32com. And then i add it a filter with this date format!

```
time = datetime.today() + timedelta(hours=5, minutes=-10)
timeFormatted = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S.000000-000")
```

The system wmi format have a GTM 0, but my pc is GTM -5 that is why i am adding 5 hours.

Query:

```
query = "Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent where (EventType = 1 or EventType = 2) and TimeGenerated >= " + "\"" + timeFormatted + "\""
```

2003 is so limiting!

Thanks all